# Associated object not created, duplicate empty insert statement created for original object created (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I have a fairly simple has many / belongs to relationship model: Reports have many Records have many Related Publishers. The belongs to objects have a foreign key to ID their parent.

However, I cannot save any 'Related Publishers'. Or rather I 'can', where the commit transaction returns true, but the Related Record is not created and the corresponding SQLite3 command does not make sense.

Why is the SQLite action generated by Rails the command to create an empty Record? Why is the save of the Related Publishers circumvented?

In `rails console`, with some output truncated

```rb
> @report = Report.new => #<Report id: nil, ... >
> @record = @report.records.build(leid: 1234567890) => #<Record id: nil, leid: 1234567890, ...>
> @related_publisher = @record.related_publishers.build(sid: 9876)
 => #<RelatedPublisher id: nil, ..., sid: 9876, ...>
> @report.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (4.5ms)  INSERT INTO "reports" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 07 May 2014 11:20:50 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 07 May 2014 11:20:50 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "records" ("created_at", "leid", "report_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 07 May 2014 11:20:50 UTC +00:00], ["leid", 1234567890], ["report_id", 22], ["updated_at", Wed, 07 May 2014 11:20:50 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "records" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 07 May 2014 11:20:50 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 07 May 2014 11:20:50 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
 => true
> RelatedPublisher.all
RelatedPublisher Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "related_publishers".* FROM "related_publishers"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

(Using Rails 4.0.4 with sqlite3 3.7.13 with gem version 1.3.9 and Ruby 2.0.0p353 on Mac OSX 10.9.2

---

app/models/report.rb

```rb
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records
end
```

app/models/record.rb

```rb
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report

  has_many :related_publishers
end
```

app/models/related_publisher.rb

```rb
class RelatedPublisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record
end
```

---

From `schema.rb`

```rb
  create_table "records", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "leid"
    t.integer  "sid"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "url"
    t.string   "join_date"
    t.string   "join_ip"
    t.string   "country"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "report_id"
    t.boolean  "ipAddressMatch"
    t.boolean  "whoisAddressMatch"
    t.integer  "recommendation"
  end

  add_index "records", ["report_id"], name: "index_records_on_report_id"

  create_table "related_publishers", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "leid"
    t.integer  "sid"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "url"
    t.string   "join_date"
    t.string   "join_ip"
    t.string   "country"
    t.integer  "record_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "related_publishers", ["record_id"], name: "index_related_publishers_on_record_id"

  create_table "reports", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "report_type"
    t.string   "upload_data_file_path"
    t.string   "completed_data_file_path"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "ltn_username"
  end
```

Comment: You did `x = @record.related_records.new`, which will create a new blank object. Then you `x.save`, which saved the blank object.

Comment: Thanks, @JustinWood You were right: that was the incorrect way to build the object. Unfortunately the problem remains -- please see the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen `#new` when building an association. Quoting from the [Active Record Associations docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) you will find

```
4.3.1.14 collection.build(attributes = {}, ...)
```

The `collection.build` method returns one or more new objects of the associated type. These objects will be instantiated from the passed attributes, and the link through their foreign key will be created, but the associated objects will not yet be saved.

which seems to be what you want to achieve in your `irb` session. In your case this should translate into

```
@record.related_records.build(val: "related")
@record.save
```

(note that you `save` the parent, it will store its changed children too)

Alternatively you may use

```
4.3.1.15 collection.create(attributes = {})
```

The `collection.create` method returns a new object of the associated type. This object will be instantiated from the passed attributes, the link through its foreign key will be created, and, once it passes all of the validations specified on the associated model, the associated object will be saved.

if the newly created record should be saved right away (and the parent object is saved already).

Comment: Very helpful, thank you, @Patru. Unfortunately the available methods seem backward and so build_related_record not available :/ (See edits to original question.) Can you help once again?

Comment: Sorry, I quoted the wrong section, 4.1 deals with `belongs_to` as you correctly determined, [4.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) deals with `has_many`, there you would find `4.3.1.14 collection.build(attributes = {}, …)` which translates to `@record.related_records.build(…)` in your case. So you where a lot closer than I thought. Will have to update my answer after dinner ...

Comment: Very sorry to do this, but I'm still getting very similar weirdness: INSERT INTO "records" is generating bad data in that table, and no sign of any Related Records -- see the most recent edits.

Comment: Well, I am very sorry then. I just tried this on one of my `has_many`-relations and it generated a perfect `insert`. I am really at a loss why your model would try to insert into the `records` table. The `insert` seems rather empty though, could you add an attribute of `RelatedRecord` in your `.build` call? I can hardly believe the table is mistaken *and* it tries to `insert` into `records` instead of `update`. Could you print the `@record` object?

Comment: I think I have all of the details in there now, and you can see I'm passing an attribute to the builds. I also rebuilt the app to try to reduce the complexity in investigating the error.

Comment: Your new example is more clear as you build all three anew, the `report`, the `record` and the `related_record`, however I am really puzzled that `ActiveRecord` is trying to insert into `record` twice. There might be a remote chance that some `AREL` magic gets confused by the two `records` that are `has_many`, but of course it should not be that way. Could you try to make `RelatedRecord` more unique (i.e. by calling it `RelatedRcord`?

Comment: Blurgh... rebuilt the model again with the name change as you suggested (truncated for length): @related_publisher.save #=> SQL (2.6ms)  INSERT INTO "reports" ...
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "records" ...
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "records" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 02 May 2014 11:32:58 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 02 May 2014 11:32:58 UTC +00:00]]

Comment: If it still inserts into `records` twice then you must have confused ActiveRecord somehow. At the very least I would expect it to at least try to save the `leid` you set, but it just seems to forget about the records. I am running out of ideas what it could be. Could you provide the relevant portion out of your `schema.rb` to show us the ruby definition of your database table?

Comment: OK, I've added the ActiveRecord::Schema.define() do block of the again-rebuilt app. Maybe you can see something in there that shouldn't be there?

Comment: With these definitions your console output is probably not in sync anymore. I guess your related class is now `RelatedPublisher`, but it still tries to insert into `records` twice. Could you provide the updated output? I still fail to see an error.

Comment: I've rebuilt the question from the original app code and db, but with the name change you recommended, and removed some of the truncation. In the interest of shipping the app, I will build the associations manually for now. But if you see something in the corrected code ... Thanks again for your help so far!